# Guardar o usuário - Angular2/4

Tags: angular

Sou novo no angular. Me tire um dúvida como poderia salvar me usuário logado, da forma que eu não perca meu usuário se o navegar for recarregado ? Como se fosse uma sessão em PHP. Obrigado pela atenção.﻿

Comment: Muito Obrigado :D

Answer (score 1):

Você pode setar o usuário logado no localStorage. Por exemplo: Ao efetuar o login, você pode verificar o usuário no back-end (no teu caso, php) e setar diretamente no localStorage. localStorage.setItem("usuario", usuario);